# Why does "a" > "b" evaluates to false? (How does PHP compares string characters)

Tags: php, character, string-comparison

Why does `"a" > "b"` evaluates to false?

It is offcourse because of the alphabet. But how does PHP know that `a` is smaller than `b`?

```
var_dump("a" > "b"); //boolean false
```

Comment: [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) values is the reason, e.g. `97 > 98` ? = `FALSE`

Comment: @Rizier123 Good answer. So its safe to say that the types of variables depend on the context, which is also the case for values.

Comment: Yes, I think I get what you mean. (e.g. `8` is a integer and `8.0` a float and `"abc"` a string)

Comment: FYI: You can take a tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see how this site works and where everything is! (Welcome on SO :D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how does php knows that "a" is smaller then "b"?

PHP takes the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) values of the characters and compare them. So this is how PHP decides which character is "smaller" than the other one.

**ASCII table:**

[image: ASCII table]

So in your example:

```
a = 97  //'97' is the ASCII value from 'a'
b = 98  //'98' is the ASCII value from 'b'
```

```
var_dump("a" > "b"); //boolean false
var_dump(97 > 98);   //The same
```

You can get the ASCII value of a character with [`ord()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php), e.g.

```
echo ord("a");  //output 97
```

And the opposite is [`chr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) which gives you the character to the ASCII value, e.g.

```
echo chr(97);  //output a
```

And for more information about [`ASCII`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).